# Is it a solvable problem to generate a regular expression that matches some input set?

Tags: regex, algorithm, compiler-theory

I provide some input set which contains known separated number of text blocks.

I want to make a program that automatically generate 1 or more regular expressions each of which matches every text block in the input set.

I see some relatively easy ways to implement a brute-force search. But I'm not an expert in compilers theory. That's why I'm curious:

1) is this problem solvable? or there are some principle impossibility to make such algorithm?

2) is it possible to achieve polynomial complexity for this algorithm and avoid brute forcing?

Comment: Is this a "fun to think about" question or is it something you want to do for a practical purpose? Not that there's anything wrong with the question either way. Just wondering.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: currently, it's definitely 'fun to think about' question.  But it also can be a useful tool for searching templates in inputs (especially, for parsing logs from different tools).

Comment: Considering @Tomas Brambora's answer, you must specify a cost function. There will be a solution (perhaps not easy to find). Good problem, though.

Comment: Is the problem to find the least greedy regex that matches various inputs from a known set?

Comment: Is the input set finite? If it is, then there's an obvious solution involving `|`. If it isn't, then not all languages are regular, so depending on the set and on how "extended" the regex syntax is that you're using, there might not exist a regex which matches all the inputs and nothing else. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language

Comment: Do you want a regex which matches only the items in the input set and nothing else? As Steve said that's trivially solvable in linear time. Or do you want to match all items which are in some way similar to the ones in the set? In that case you'll need to define how you want to measure similarity otherwise the problem is painfully underspecified.

Comment: @sepp2k: it probably should search and find patterns with some predefined level of 'variation'. Steve's suggestion (with `|`) is about the minimum 'variation'. But I'm not sure yet about how should it really work.

Answer (score 9):

".*" is one-or-more regexp that will match every text block in the input set. ;-)

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It clearly shows that the problem is solvable. The question is not precise enough to know what an acceptable regex would look like. Another regex to match the input set would be the input itself. This would match *exactly* the input. Or one could e.g. replace all digits with \d to allow more variations...

Comment: @0xA3: I think, the solution should produce something less greedy. (but that's not my downvote).

Comment: @Roman: I think you should elaborate more on what "less greedy" means. There might be many possible regular expressions between the two extremes .* and the input itself.

Comment: @0xA3 I think it should be quite obvious. OP wants it to match the input set, while fail against strings not in the input set.

Comment: @marcog - it is not obvious at all.  The question is clearly ambiguous, and none of @Roman's comments really clarify it.

Comment: This will get upvoted by people who think it's funny or clever to say "Yes!" when someone asks you whether you want pizza or noodles for dinner.  People (like me) who think it's annoying will downvote.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, there are a huge number of regular expressions (actually, an infinite number) that will match a given set of inputs. They range from very "greedy" expressions that will match everything

```
.*
```

To very non "greedy" expression that will match exactly the input set

```
InputA OR inputB OR inputC etc
```

In between those two you can vary the expression in a variety of ways to make it more and less greedy (eg, replace specific digits with an expression which matches any digit, etc).

You'll have to tell us a little more about the problem for us to know where in that range of possible answers is the correct one ;)

Comment: there's no real problem yet. Currently, I'm working on parsing and merging logs from different tools (not so many, only 4). And I thought: "it would be nice and it should be possible to generate regular expressions automatically for these files with logs. That's all yet. I want to gather some ideas here.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, in a comment you clarified that you want to match all strings which are either equal to one of the strings in the input set, or only differ from one of them within a given level of 'variation'. Since you didn't define 'variation' exactly, I'm going to use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Given a string `s` and an integer `n`, you can build the regex, which matches exactly all strings that have a Levenshtein distance of `n` or less to that string, like this:

First we write a function that given `s` and `n` returns a list of simple regexen which when together match all strings with a distance of `n` or less to `s`. Here "simple regex" means a regex which only contains literal characters and wildcards.

For `n=0` that function just returns `[s]`. Otherwise it computes the list for `n-1` and then goes through each item in it. For each item `r` and each position `i` where `0 <= i < length(r)`, it adds the following regexen to the list:

- The regex where `.` has been added to `r` at position `i`.
- The regex where the `i`th character of `r` has been deleted.
- The regex where the `i`th character of `r` has been replaced by a `.`.

Now to calculate the regex for a given set of strings and a given value for `n`, we calculate the list for each string and then `or` all the regexen together into one big regex.

Note that this will lead to very big regexen very soon.

Comment: interesting approach. I need some time to understand it completely. //a little offtopic: I haven't managed yet how to be notified about new responses after the envelope was turned off. That's why I repsond not very fast now..

Comment: @Roman: On the top-left corner of the site there's the stack exchange logo. If you have any unread answers or comments, there is a number in a red circle next to the logo telling you how many unread messages you have. When you click it, you get a list. Also when you ask a question, there's a check box at the bottom asking you whether you want to be notified by e-mail each time you get an answer.

Comment: +1, sure, you *could* build a regex for matching anything within a given Levenshtein distance that way, in much the same way as you could write a message by carefully striking a piece of paper with a hammer many times :)

Answer (score 3):

http://txt2re.com/ might be what you want.

Comment: +1 nice! That will probably come in handy someday. But I think the idea would be that instead of giving it a single input string and then having the tool guide you to figuring out the regex, you would give it several input strings, and then it would automatically figure out the regex.